# Modifing Selection Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, range

At the moment i have the following problem, i'm applying span tags with the applyStyle Method from CKEDITOR 4.x. But when a span is partial selected and i execute the applyStyle method a new span will be made with the selection, but the other half of the selected span isn't restored and loses his span.

First Question: Is it possible to prevent partial selection of a certain element?

IF NOT My Second Question: Is it possible to extend the Selection only on one side, the side where the span(With a certain class or attribute)  is partial selected. So that it will be fully selected for processing.

A Example:

```
This is 'my text <span class"testClass">, This' is </span> Other Text
```

And now we want a solution to create:

```
This is  <span class"testClass2"> my text, This</span> <span class"testClass">  is </span> Other Text
```

Please take notice of the following:

The hard part in this is to maintain the html structure. when half of the selection is in an other block level element, it may not brake! That is the reason that i started using the applyStyle method.

Comment: I'll analyse your problem later, but I need to write this: welcome to wysiwygs world :D We deal with this on a daily basis.

Comment: I love it, I'm already thinking about a new solution for this.. but THE solution i didn't found yet.  The problem for you guys is that everyone thinks that everything is already made.. But the miss the fun part if everything is already fixed. haha

Comment: What is the most secure way to see if a whole block is selected? if i can find out that, i think i do get one of my ways working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking and trying for hours. And chose to make an enlarge function myself to expand the selection. I made my own enlarge/expand function as i wanted to have more control which the enlarge of CKEDITOR doesn't provide.

The code:

```
            //Vars
        var firstNode = range.startContainer.getParent();
        var lastNode = range.endContainer.getParent();

        //Make end Get full if is tcElement
        if(lastNode.type === CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && lastNode.getName() === "myElement")
        {
            range.setEndAfter(lastNode);

        }

        //Make end Get full if is tcElement
        if(firstNode.type === CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && firstNode.getName() === "myElement")
        {
            range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
        }

        range.select();
```

Other nice piece of code, which isn't very hard but can be useful for other people.

This code i used to split the code in 2 or 3 parts.. where part 1 and 3 are the partial selection if existed.

```
            Spliting to multiple ranges
        //Vars
        var newRanges = [];
        var allWithinRangeParent = range.getCommonAncestor().getChildren();
        var firstNode = range.startContainer;
        var lastNode = range.endContainer;
        var firstNodeStart = range.startOffset;
        var lastNodeEnd = range.endOffset;

        //TODO make if to check if this needs to be made.
        //make end partial
        var newEndRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
        newEndRange.selectNodeContents( lastNode );
        newEndRange.endOffset = lastNodeEnd;
        newRanges.push(newEndRange);

        //TODO make if to check if this needs to be made.
        //Make start partial
        var newStartRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
        newStartRange.selectNodeContents( firstNode );
        newStartRange.startOffset = firstNodeStart;
        newRanges.push(newStartRange);

        //Make center selection.
        var tempRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
        tempRange.setStartBefore(firstNode.getParent().getNext());
        tempRange.setEndAfter(lastNode.getParent().getPrevious());
        newRanges.push(tempRange);

        selection.selectRanges(newRanges);
```

Answer (score 3):

> First Question: Is it possible to prevent partial selection of a certain element?

Hmm... You can check placeholder plugin's sample - it uses non-editable inline elements to create those placeholders which at least on Chrome cannot be partially selected. Though, I think it's not a satisfying solution for you :)

Another possible solution is using `editor#selectionChange` event on which you can check if one of selection ends is located inside that element and if yes, set it before or after that element. It'd look like (I haven't tested this code, it's just a proto):

```
editor.on( 'selectionChange', function( evt ) {
    var sel = evt.data.selection,
        range = sel.getRanges()[ 0 ];

    if ( protectedElement.contains( range.startContainer ) || protectedElement.equals( range.startContainer ) )
        range.setStartAt( protectedElement, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START );
    if ( protectedElement.contains( range.endContainer ) || protectedElement.equals( range.endContainer ) )
        range.setEndAt( protectedElement, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_END );

    sel.selectRanges( [ range ] );
} );
```

Although, this kind of solutions are always dangerous and can cause many unpredictable situations. But it may be worth checking it.

Back to the root of your problem - I understand that you want to create styles which work on the same level - i.e. only one can be applied in one place. This isn't possible using styling system. You would have to prepare range before applying style. The code would be similar to the `selectionChange` listener - you check if ends are anchored in style element, if yes you need to move range's ends out of it. The only question is how to exclude entire element from range in this situation:

```
<p>foo[bar<span class="st1">bom</span>bim]foo</p>
```

The result should be two ranges:

```
<p>foo[bar]<span class="st1">bom</span>[bim]foo</p>
```

Unfortunately current range's API does not include helpful method like `range#exclude`, therefore you need to implement yours. I would try doing this with [walker](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker). Iterate from range's start to end and remember all style elements. If you'll do this in both directions you'll gather also partially selected elements on both ends, so the first step I described will be unnecessary. When you'll have list of elements which you want to exclude from range, then you just need to create ranges at both ends and between these elements - this part should be easy. [Element#getPosition](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-getPositionedAncestor) will be helpful, but you'll need to check its code to understand how to use it because it isn't documented.

Comment: i'm thinking that it's not needed to exlude the span from the selection. Possibly it's possible to make separated ranges of the partial selected spans. because in this case the apply style does do his work how i suspected it to do it. But now i see a bug in my code, my code shouldn't have spans in spans(which are made by me). And this does happen when applyStyle apply's to a selection in another span. But this should be fixable with a breakTag check. for now i'll keep on trying working with walker. And i'm thinking of making a range split function for elements. that it makes ranges for each el

Comment: Like you said CKEDITOR.dom.element.unselectable( ) Also get's very close but's prevent me from editing the element. but how it handles the selection is great.. something in that direction would be great. i'll keep searching